# Cloud Foundry v2 in Grails

Tags: mysql, grails, groovy, cloud, cloud-foundry

I have a grails project and I want to deploy it on Cloud Foundry, but the the console shows this:

```
[CONTAINER] n.spring.CloudProfileApplicationContextInitializer INFO    Adding 'cloud' to list of active profiles
[CONTAINER] g.CloudPropertySourceApplicationContextInitializer INFO    Adding 'cloud' PropertySource to ApplicationContext
[CONTAINER] udAutoReconfigurationApplicationContextInitializer INFO    Adding cloud service auto-reconfiguration to ApplicationContext
[CONTAINER] ing.DataSourceCloudServiceBeanFactoryPostProcessor INFO    Auto-reconfiguring beans of type javax.sql.DataSource
[CONTAINER] ing.DataSourceCloudServiceBeanFactoryPostProcessor INFO    No beans of type javax.sql.DataSource found. Skipping auto-reconfiguration.
[CONTAINER] lina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/] SEVERE  Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext           SEVERE  Error listenerStart
    ... 5 more
[CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase    INFO    Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [135] milliseconds.
[CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext           SEVERE  Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
[CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader       WARNING The web application [] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
[CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader       WARNING The web application [] registered the JDBC driver [org.h2.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
[CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader       WARNING The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:142)
```

I think that it's a problem of DB Conex but I don't know to fix it. I use MySQL in my app and the service plan ClearDB MySQL Database Spark DB.

My `Datasource.groovy` is:

```
import org.springframework.cloud.CloudFactory

def cloud

try {
  cloud = new CloudFactory().cloud
} catch(e) {}

dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
    username = "root"
    password = "root"
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = true
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
    //cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider'
}
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/bbddSRL"
            username="root"
            password="root"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/bbddSRL"
            username="root"
            password="root"
        }
    }
production {
        dataSource {
          pooled = true
          dbCreate = 'update'
          driverClassName = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'

          if (cloud) {
            def dbInfo = cloud.getServiceInfo('mysql-instance') //mysql-instance is the name of the ClearDB's service.
            url = dbInfo.jdbcUrl
            username = dbInfo.userName
            password = dbInfo.password
          } else {
            url = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/bbddSRLprod'
            username = 'root'
            password = 'root'
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Any anwers or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try eliminating the datasource block where you define dialect.  You will have to still define the items in that block but do it in the datasource of each environment. I did this because it seemed like any changes that I made to the datasource within the environment had no effect.

Comment: I removed the datasource block but the problem is still. :(

Comment: Nobody knows something? =(